# how to scrape trending song names from music websites like hungama or saavn

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-scraping

My need is to get top trending songs/albums name from hungama or saavn like that. I used web scraping packages from npm and tried to retrieve data from websites. Referred many packages like cheerio, jsdom, request etc. Finally found a simple package called "osmosis". here is my code using osmosis.

```
const osmosis = require('osmosis');

osmosis
    .get('http://www.hungama.com/all/top-songs-51/21825/')
    .find('.listing div.block-cont div.song div.song-name')
    .follow('h4')
    .log(console.log)
```

This will return output like this:

```
(get) loaded [get] http://www.hungama.com/all/top-songs-51/21825/  
(find) found 12 results for ".listing div.block-cont div.song div.song-name" 
(follow) url: 
                                            
                                            Mersal Arasan                                        
(follow) url: 
                                            
                                            Yaanji                                       
(follow) url: 
                 
(follow) loaded [get] http://www.hungama.com/all/top-songs-51/21825/Mersal%20Arasan  
(follow) loaded [get] http://www.hungama.com/all/top-songs-51/21825/Yaanji
```

But i need output only the song names. while using other packages like cheerio, how to mention my particular data class while finding (like how to mention "div.listing div.song div.song-name h4"). Is there any other easy way to to this operation. Please help me to get my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const osmosis = require('osmosis');

osmosis
    .get('http://www.hungama.com/all/top-songs-51/21825/')
    .find('div.song-name')
    // ^^^^^ assuming this is the css selector for the song name
    .set('songName')
    .data(function(names){
            console.log(names); // display the list of songName sa object.
         })
    .log(console.log)
    .error(console.log)
    .debug(console.log)
```